# jQuery - I'm trying to bind arrow keys to a moving picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, binding

I need to move a stickman picture across the screen using the arrow keys. I can't seem to find how. I've tried everything I found, still, it didn't work.
Here's the [link](http://dotcomaftereverything.com/jquery/game.php).

Code:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sitting').hide();  
            $(document).keydown(function(e){
                var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which,
                    arrow = { left:37, up:38, right: 39, down: 40 };
                switch (keyCode {
                case arrow.left:
                    if(!$('#sitting').is(':visible')){
                    $('#img,#sitting').animate({
                        left:'-=60px'
                    },300,"linear");
                    }
                break;
                case arrow.up:
                break;
                case arrow.right:
                    if(!$('#sitting').is(':visible')){
                    $('#img,#sitting').animate({
                        left:'+=60px'
                    },300,"linear");
                    }
                break;
                case arrow.down:
                break;
                }
            });
        $('#sit').click(function(){
            $('#img').fadeToggle(-100,function(){
                $('#sitting').fadeToggle(-100);
            });
        });
    }); 
    </script>
    <button id='left'><<</button><button id='right'>>></button><button id='sit'>Sit Down/Stand up</button><br />
    <img src='/jquery/sprites/spritePerson.png' id='img' style='position: absolute; margin-top: 375px;' /><img id='sitting' src='/jquery/sprites/spriteSitting.png' style='position: fixed; margin-top: 375px;'><img id='tree' src='/jquery/sprites/spriteTree.png' style='position: absolute; margin-top: 100px; margin-left: 700px;' /><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Think your code to be working . only you missed a bracket code in `switch (keyCode)`.

How ever you need to work around your code. some of your code can be optimized.

like.

1. Always use stop(true) before you call animate method. This stops the queue of animate .
   like `$(selector).stop(true).animate({});`
2. Why you need to make a new object of arrow . you can directly use key code in case;
3. make a reference to your selector so it will not traverse all the time to get element.

see jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bxAtd/